# Possible spam notification even when there are no links in post

Tags: discussion, support

I was reviewing few posts and noticed that after reviewing a particular post I get this error

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

I immediately reverted back to check what was the 'probable' spam link. **When I looked back, there wasn't any link at all**. I'm not sure why I got this notification.

Am I missing something while reviewing ?

[Question I reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879736/visual-studio-how-to-chain-build-of-projects-with-different-bitness) - [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879736/visual-studio-how-to-chain-build-of-projects-with-different-bitness)

[Next question where I got the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880562/barcode-scanner-red-light-not-showing-in-android-studio) - [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880562/barcode-scanner-red-light-not-showing-in-android-studio)

**Screenshots** -

[image]
[image]

Comment: You say it was "*after* reviewing a particular post." Was it *after* you reviewed these posts? Or *when you were looking at them*? In the first screenshot, there's no warning, but in the second there is. Can you clarify?

Comment: It was ***when I was looking at them***. When I reviewed the first question, the webpage moved on to the next question and then on that question I saw this warning. I hadn't reviewed the second question at that moment.

Comment: Then only the question where the warning appeared is relevant. The warning has nothing to do with the other question. I don't know exactly why the system was suspicious of the second one, but it may have to do with the phrase "barcode scanner," which is likely used in a fair amount of spam.

Comment: I think I got this wrong then. Till now I thought it gave me a warning for the last question I reviewed.

Comment: That's why it says "***this post***..." :)

Comment: Yep. Totally my bad. :) Thanks Ed !

Comment: See the proposed FAQ on Meta.SE: ["The review system suggested something was probably spam, what should I do when I see this?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216399/the-review-system-suggested-something-was-probably-spam-what-should-i-do-when-i)

Answer (score 7):

Posts don't have to contain links in order to be spam. They can also contain phone numbers and emails, or just plain information about a product hoping you'll be interested enough to look it up. Sometimes the algorithms that attempt to detect these things pick up false positives. That's why the message says *possible* spam.

Answer (score 3):

A post doesn't need to have a link in it for it to be spam.  I.e:

Call 863-555-9385 to get **SUPER CHEAP** programming books.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when somebody has flagged the post as spam.

Then the system knows that there's a reasonable chance that it is spam, and warns subsequent reviewers.

Comment: It also happens on audits, but neither is the case here: no spam flags, and these are not review audits.